# Why my block admin show 2 grid view in magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9

Why my block admin show 2 grid view in magento 1.9.2

```
<?php

class Ig_Tobi_Block_Adminhtml_Page extends
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'ig_tobi';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_page';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('ig_tobi')->__('Page');
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install firebug in Firefox (if not already installed).
- Open page in Firefox and check console tab.
- You should see some JavaScript errors in console, which should give you clue.

This issue is related to JavaScript conflict.